# How to make a button with inside border

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a responsive button that has an "inner border" if that makes sense, see attached picture for what I'm talking about.

[image: button preview]

Some of my buttons are a bit wider than others because the button text is longer which is where the responsive part comes in. I created this effect by putting my button into a container div, here's the code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="ttw_button_container">
<a class="ttw_button">START THE JOURNEY</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.ttw_button_container {
    background: #27d9b4;
    width: 330px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
a.ttw_button{  
    background: #27d9b4;
    color: {{ settings.btn_text_color }};
    border: 1px solid white;
    padding: 6px 52px;
    margin: 4px 0 0 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;      
    font-size: 19px;
    text-transform: {{ settings.button_font_style }};
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 200ms ease 0s;
    -ms-transition: all 200ms ease 0s;
    -o-transition: all 200ms ease 0s;
    transition: all 200ms ease 0s;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Is there a way I can have the container div resize itself to fit the button? Currently I'm manually editing the container's width to fit each button but would ideally like this to be done automatically. Is there a way to do this using just CSS or do we need to bring javascript into the mix?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried box-shadow property?

Comment: @FelipeKM of course not yet.

Comment: I'm going off guesswork without a JSFiddle to mess around in, but try removing the width/height properties on the div, and then add "display: inline-block;"

Comment: @Katana314 he is using a container just to create the button effect, which can be solved by using `box-shadow` instead, so just forget about the container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure there is, here is a JS fiddle that will accept and scale to any amount of text in there.

http://jsfiddle.net/T9Wk7/

Instead of using a width on your container just use padding:

```
.ttw_button_container {
    background: #27d9b4;
    padding: 4px 10px;
    margin: 4px 0;
    display: inline-block;
}
a.ttw_button{  
    background: #27d9b4;
    color: {{ settings.btn_text_color }};
    border: 1px solid white;
    padding: 6px 52px;
    font-weight: bold;      
    font-size: 19px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

If you want to lose the containing div all together you can do what some of the comments suggest and just use box-shadow:

```
a.ttw_button{  
    background: #27d9b4;
    color: {{ settings.btn_text_color }};
    border: 1px solid white;
    padding: 6px 52px;
    font-weight: bold;      
    font-size: 19px;
    display: inline-block;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 6px #27d9b4
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 6px #27d9b4
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 6px #27d9b4
}
```

Here is a JSfiddle showing that: http://jsfiddle.net/T9Wk7/1/

Comment: Thanks! Clear and concise answer. Going with the box-shadow method.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a really simple solution using box-shadow that requires less markup and less CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/Jdzpv/3/.

HTML:

```
<a class="ttw_button">START THE JOURNEY</a>
```

CSS:

```
.ttw_button {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 19px;
    background: #27d9b4;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px #27d9b4,
                inset 0 0 0 1px #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

And, here's a solution that should work in older browsers that do not support `box-shadow`.  This one uses `outline` and `border` declarations: http://jsfiddle.net/Jdzpv/5/.

HTML:

```
<a class="ttw_button">START THE JOURNEY</a>
```

CSS:

```
.ttw_button {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 19px;
    background: #27d9b4;
    outline: 5px solid #27d9b4;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
.ttw_button_container {
    background: #27d9b4;
    width: 330px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding:6px;
}
a.ttw_button{  
    background: #27d9b4;
    color: {{ settings.btn_text_color }};
    border: 1px solid white;
    padding: 6px;
    line-height:35px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;      
    font-size: 19px;
    text-transform: {{ settings.button_font_style }};
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 200ms ease 0s;
    -ms-transition: all 200ms ease 0s;
    -o-transition: all 200ms ease 0s;
    transition: all 200ms ease 0s;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    text-align:center;    
}
```

Comment: using fixed widths on the container does not accomplish the OPs problem of making it responsive...